# Do I need a licence to check in/out code in a TFS Server?

Tags: tfs, msdn

I`m trying to understand the licensing of MSDN. If I just want to perform check in/out , see History and similar operations as a member of a TFS Team of Developers Do I need an MSDN license ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> To license TFS server      , you’ll need a **TFS server license** and a
>   Windows operating system license (Windows Server is best) for each
>   machine running TFS, plus **a client access license for each person
>   connecting to TFS**. Client access licenses (CALs) aren’t required for
>   people who just access work items – assign them “Stakeholder” access,
>   which is free.
>
> Extensions to TFS such as **Test Manager**, Package Management, and
>   Private Pipelines require an additional purchase. Some TFS Extensions
>   are included with **Visual Studio Enterprise subscriptions** and many
>   others are free. Paid extensions can also be purchased monthly, no
>   Visual Studio subscription is required.

In your case, if you want users to check in/out, view source control history, you still need a CAL. Which means you still need a MSDN subscription to handle this. Unless, people who just access work items – simply assign them “Stakeholder” access, which is free.

Unlike the Classic Purchasing above, if you don't want to buy a MSDN subscription.
Suggest you to use Modern Purchasing.

> The most advantage: No need to make a 3-year purchasing commitment for
>   TFS—you can pay month-to-month and cancel any time. For example: Buy
>   VSTS for TFS CALs. When you buy VSTS users (starting at $6/month),
>   those same users have a TFS CAL and can connect to any TFS in your
>   organization. If those users also need TFS extensions like Test
>   Manager or Package Management, or if you need additional Private
>   Pipelines for your team, you can purchase these through the Visual
>   Studio Marketplace. All VSTS charges are month-to-month. See detailed
>   [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-access-tfs-test-hub?view=tfs-2018).

For more info you could take a look at this official doc: [**Team Foundation Server Pricing**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/)

---

Besides, If you want to double confirm this and  know more information about TFS license, you could call 1-800-426-9400, Monday through Friday, 6:00 A.M. to 6:00 P.M. (Pacific Time) to speak directly to a Microsoft licensing specialist, and you can get more detail information from there. Worldwide customers can use the Guide to Worldwide Microsoft Licensing Sites to find contact information in their locations: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/